how sharepoint build search link description
in sharepoint 2019 search results under any link there is description showing some lines
how sharepoint 2019 is chose what words to be description and how to modify it
I cheche search databases for link description but didn't find it

SharePoint 2019 chooses the words for the link description in search results based on the content of the page being linked to. It uses an algorithm to select the most relevant and informative text to display as the description. To modify the link description, you can modify the content of the page being linked to.

in my situation page content is good but sharepoint search showing description in not clear way and have dots in between some words so is there is a way i can edit this description
